# React Table create new editable row on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Hi I am creating react table where i have to add a new editable table row in the table where i could add a new row item to the table this is what i have so far.

```
   <DefaultButton
              text='Add QnA'
              primary={ true }
              onClick={this.addNewQnaToTable}
            />

        <ReactTable
          data={this.state.items}


          PaginationComponent={Pagination}
          columns={[
            {
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Questions",
                  accessor: "Questions",
                 Cell: this.renderQuestionsEdit
                },
                {
                  Header: "Answer",
                  accessor: "Answer",
                  Cell: this.renderEditable
                },
                {
                  Header: "Classification",
                  accessor: "Classification",
                  Cell: this.renderEditableDropdown
                },
                {
                  Header: "Actions",
                  accessor: "Actions",
                  Cell: ({row}) => (<div>
                    <button onClick={()=>this.deleteQnA({row})}>Delete Question</button>
                   </div> )
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
```

so it renders correctly when i edit the table, all cells which has content in it becomes editable with my corresponding cel renderers. so i decided what if i insert a new blank items to the table so that it can be editable and this is my code to add a new row:

```
 public addNewQnaToTable(): void {
    console.log("add inline form");
    //add new editable row to table
    let newQnA = {
      Questions: "[{'label':' ','value':' '}]",
      Answer: " ",
      Classification: " "
    }

     this.setState((oldstate)=>({
      items: [...oldstate.items, newQnA]
     }));
     console.log("new row added");
  }
```

but nothing is happening and the row is not being editable. how do add a new row to input new items to the table? i cant find anything from the docs of React Table

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Hi @brewcrazy, what i did was to insert empty (blank) values to the rows so that it will render editable, what was happening in react table is that it needs to have value first before it can be rendered as editable.

Comment: Isn't that what your question above was trying to accomplish? Did you get it working? Would you mind sharing your solution as an answer?

Comment: hi @brewcrazy, crazy but i managed to get it working using the same code above I am sorry if i'm not being helpful here :O  but let me share my code:
public addNewQnaToTable(): void {
      let newQnA = {
             //obj property
      };
    const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
      ...arr.slice(0, index),
      newItem,
      ...arr.slice(index)
    ];
    console.log(newQnA);
    this.setState(oldstate => ({
     qnaItems: insert(oldstate.qnaItems, 0, newQnA)
    }));
  }

Comment: as long as the state is updated the react table should pick up the updated state and render the table with the added item.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I had come up with something that worked to add the new row, but was struggling with the row being added to the top. Looks like you have a good solution for that. Now to figure out how to make all columns in the row editable once its added.

Comment: Hi @brewcrazy , my code adds the element on top :D you can use it to implement yours

Comment: Do you have your new row editable? I can't seem to figure out how to make just 1 row editable when I add it (rather than a whole column). I also can't find any examples online for that

Comment: Hi @brewcrazy, ah. in my case i didnt need to have only one row editable unfortunately i also do not know how to  make only one row editable .